# PDO : prepare with bindvalue and like %

Tags: php, sql, pdo, prepare

I've looked over an hour on various website but I couldn't solve my problem.

So here is the code that works:

```
$animes = array();
    $q = $this->_db->query('SELECT id, nom, nom_id FROM animes WHERE nom LIKE "%code%"');
    while ($data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $animes[] = new Anime($data);
    }
    return $animes;
```

And here is the one that doesn't work :

```
$animes = array();
$q = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT id, nom, nom_id FROM animes WHERE nom LIKE :n');
$q->bindValue(':n',"%code%",PDO::PARAM_STR);
    while ($data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
     {
         $animes[] = new Anime($data);
     }
return $animes;`
```

I use `%code%` in this example but it will be used with `$info` which is a `$_POST` value that I retrieve.

How can I solve it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you did not `execute()`.

after binding you need to execute then fetch:

```
$q->bindValue(':n',"%code%",PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->execute();  
while ($data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

you can bind like this with php variable:

```
$q->bindValue(':n','%'.$var.'%',PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: +1 I actually think that his actual problem is in `'%'.$var.'%'` part, and yes, it wasn't executed!

Comment: omg, thank you, I really did not see that ... it works fine now ! thank you